# How to rebind C-backspace in projectile find file?

Tags: key-bindings, helm, projectile

I've installed helm and projectile modes and I wanted to restore the previous behaviour of the C-backspace binding to kill whole last word.

In these modes, when looking for a file (after pressing C-x-f), this binding is changed to turn on/off auto expansion (it seems to run the `helm-ff-run-toggle-auto-update` function).

I've put this in my init.el:

```
(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "<C-backspace>") 'backward-kill-word)
(define-key helm-projectile-find-file-map (kbd "<C-backspace>") 'backward-kill-word)
```

And when I run `describe-variable` for `helm-find-files-map` and `helm-projectile-find-file-map` they indeed contain the `(C-backspace . backward-kill-word)` entry.

Unfortunately, pressing C-backspace in helm-find-file still toggles auto expansion instead of deleting the last path entry. How to achieve this?

---

This is the minimal example of init.el contents that should reproduce this behaviour:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

(require 'helm)
(require 'helm-config)

(projectile-global-mode)
(setq projectile-completion-system 'helm)
(helm-projectile-on)

(helm-mode 1)

(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "<C-backspace>") 'backward-kill-word)
(define-key helm-projectile-find-file-map (kbd "<C-backspace>") 'backward-kill-word)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `helm-mode` enabled, the ordinary `find-file` command will use `helm-read-file-map`, so you should use:

```
(define-key helm-read-file-map (kbd "<C-backspace>") #'backward-kill-word)
```

But if you are using helm, `helm-find-files` provides more features than `find-file` so you are suggested to use the former.